# Create a relation to a many to many relation in Laravel 5

Tags: orm, eloquent, laravel-5, relation

First, i gonna explain how my models are created. i have 3 models Teacher, Signature and Resource

A Resource belogs to a Teacher AND also Signature, and Signature and Teacher have a many to many relation.

Teacher has many Resources.
Signature has many Resources.
Teacher has many Signatures.
Signatures has many Teachers
Resources belogs to a Teacher and also belongs to a Signature.

Here is my db structure:

```
    Teachers
        id
        name

    Signature
        id
        name
        dsescription

    Resources
        id
        name
        path
        teacher_id
        signature_id

    signature_teacher //table from many to many relation doesn't have a model related to it
        id
        signature_id
        teacher_id
```

Now i want to get a resource from a teacher_id and also a signature_id
For example on Teacher model get all Resources from a given Signature
or on Signature get all the Resources from a ginven Teacher.

I try with the relation One to many in the models but this get me all te resources form a teacher or all the resources from a signature, but not a resource from a teacher and also a signature.

```
class Resource extends Model {
    public teacher(){
        return $this->belongsTo('APP\Teacher');
    }
    public signature(){
        return $this->belongsTo('APP\Signature');
    }

}


class Teacher extends Model {

    public function signatures(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Signature');
    }

    public function resources() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Resource'); //return all resources from a teacher
    // how can i get the resources with a given signature
    }

}


class Signature extends Model {

    public function teachers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teacher')
    }

    public function resources()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Resource'); //return all resources from a signature
    //how can i get all the resources with a given teacher?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$teacher = Teacher::with(['signatures.resources'], ['resources'])->find($teacherId);
```

This gives you teacher with all his resource, all his signatures, and all resources belonging to those signature

on Teacher model get all Resources from a given Signature

```
Teacher::find($teacherId)->signatures()->find($signatureId)->resources;
```

on Signature get all the Resources from a ginven Teacher

```
Signature::find($signatureId)->teachers()->find($teacherId)->resources;
```

EDIT

```
$resources = Resource::whereHas('teacher', function($q)
{
    $q->where('id', $teacherId);

})
->whereHas('signature', function($q)
{
    $q->where('id', $signatureId);

})->get();
```

Comment: ok that gonna give me the resources of a teacher that belogs to the signature. but for example i have these resources:

resource1 belogs to signature1 and teacher2.

resource2 belogs to signature2 and teacher2.

When i call
$signatureId = signature1;
$teacherId = teacher2;
Signature::find($signatureId)->teachers()->find($teacherId)->resources;

That gonna return resource1 and resource2, but resource2 doesn't belogs to a signature1.